# jqplot how to show text on highlighter

Tags: jqplot

i have an array that has 3 different values

```
var = [[11/11/12, 45, oijadsoiajsd], [12/11/12, 45, oijadsoiajsd], [13/11/12, 45, oijadsoiajsd]]
```

how can i make it so it will show the text as well, i have it set up so it shows

```
{
label: 'People Talking About This',
lineWidth:2, 
color: '#16aad7',
highlighter: {formatString: '<span class="date">(%s)</span><span lass="number">%s</span>'},
markerOptions:{
style:'filledSquare', 
color: '#16aad7'
}
},
```

please help, how can i put the text on the tooltip as well??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that if you want the system to read an extra info you need to add it so the system knows is in the array.

```
   highlighter: {
     show: true,
     sizeAdjust: 5,
     yvalues:2
   },
```

So the key here is the :

```
yvalues:2
```

if you have more than 2 data in the array and you want to read the 3rd or 4rd info in the array you have to tell the sistem that you have 2, 3 values on the yvalues.